# Throttling attempts not being recorded into database

Tags: php, security, throttling

Hi I am trying to create login throttling with object oriented php, I have successfully created it with structured code but I can not get it to work with object oriented so far heres the code:

```
public function find_failed_login($email = null) {
        if(!empty($email)) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE email = '".$this->db->escape($email)."'";
            return $this->db->query($query);
        }
    }

    public function record_failed_login($email) {

            $count = 1;
            $time = time();

            $failed_login = $this->find_failed_login($email);
            if(!$failed_login) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO {$this->table} (email, count, last_time) VALUES ('".$this->db->escape($email)."', {$count}, {$time})";
                return $this->db->query($query);
            } else {
                $query = "UPDATE {$this->table} SET email = '{$email}', count = count + 1, last_time = {$time}";
                return $this->db->query($query); 
            }

    }

    public function clear_failed_logins($email = null) {
        if(!empty($email)) {
            $failed_login = $this->find_failed_login($email);
            if(isset($failed_login)) {
                $query = "DELETE FROM {$this->table} WHERE email = '".$this->db->escape($email)."'";
                return $this->db->query($query);
            }
        }
    }

    public function throttle_failed_logins($email = null) {
        if(!empty($email)) {

            $throttle_at = 3;
            $delay_in_minutes = 1;
            $delay = 60 * $delay_in_minutes;

            $failed_login = $this->find_failed_login($email);
            if(isset($failed_login)) {  
                while($failed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($failed_login)) {

                    if(isset($failed) && $failed['count'] >= $throttle_at) {
                        $remaining_delay = ($failed['last_time'] + $delay) - time();
                        $remaining_delay_in_minutes = ceil($remaining_delay / 60);
                        return $remaining_delay_in_minutes;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and in the login page I am calling it like this:

```
$objLogin = new Login();

if($objForm->isPost('login_email')) {

        $throttle_delay = $objLogin->throttle_failed_logins($objForm->getPost('login_email'));
        if($throttle_delay > 0) {
            $objValid->add2Errors('failed_logins');
        }
```

when I try this I get no error or anything for that matter, its like it is dead code, would appreciate some professional help :)

Comment: I would ensure `throttle_failed_logins` always returns something even if it is an error. i.e. return zero if it gets to the end?

Comment: in the method I do return something in both cases or do you mean on the login page itself to return something?